# Saving Docker logs of MQTT Broker container

Tags: docker, mqtt

I am using eclipse-mosquitto broker 1.6.15 and I ask myself, why it is not possible to save the logs of the broker container in a file on my local machine. I have created and started my broker container like figured below:

```
docker pull eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.15
docker create --name mosquitto_broker eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.15
docker start mosquitto_broker
docker container logs mosquitto_broker --follow
```

When the container is running, I can see some logs in the bash console:

```
$ docker container logs mosquitto_broker --follow
1646980213: mosquitto version 1.6.15 starting
1646980213: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1646980213: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1646980213: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1646980213: mosquitto version 1.6.15 running
```

Now, I open a second bash console and try the following docker command to save these broker logs in a file on my local machine:

```
docker container logs mosquitto_broker > C:/abc/def/mosquitto_broker.log
```

Unfortunately, when I navigate to the folder C:/abc/def, I can view a new file named mosquitto_broker.log, but this file is empty! I have no idea how to save the logs... I have read the documentation about Docker's "container logs" command, but as you can see, it doesn't work. I also tried newer versions of the broker, but I face the same issue...
Another purpose might be a config file for the broker, but currently I have not found some useful websites with good examples which help. I hope, anyone of you can help me. Maybe someone did have the same issue and wants to share his or her solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the logs, docker is already doing it for you.

The default location on windows will be:

```
C:\ProgramData\docker\containers\[container_ID]\[container_ID]-json.log
```

On Linux it's

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/[container_ID]/[container-ID]-json.log
```

Where `container_ID` is the hash, not the container name. You can find the full id (not the truncated version) by running `docker ps --no-trunc`

The other problem you have is that tailing the logs outputs to both stdout and stderr so if you want to store both, you need to combine them.

```
docker logs -f mosquitto_broker > mosquitto.log 2>&1
```

The `2>&1` forces stderr to stdout which is already piped to the `mosquitto.log` file

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good to know that. And what if I have my broker container running on a virtual machine with Linux? How can I find this log file there? When I save the containers' logs with `docker container logs container_name > ./abc/def/container_name.log`, I know where to find it, because finally, a script takes these log files and does something with it.

But when I use a virtual machine, I do not really know, where Docker saves the broker's logs...

Comment: I've added the Linux location and why you are not getting what you expect in the local file.